# Adding event to calendar displays wrong time but when saved the time is correct

Tags: android, xamarin.android, calendar, android-calendar

I have a button to add an event to the calendar. The code works, the event is added correctly but when the calendar event displays to be saved the time is displayed incorrectly. The event is 4 - 6pm, the calendar add event displays 12pm - 2pm, clearly a timezone issue but when the event is saved (without changing the time) it displays correctly 4 - 6pm.

This is the code and screen shots adding the event and the result:

```
Intent eventValues = new Intent(Intent.ActionInsert);
eventValues.SetData(CalendarContract.Events.ContentUri);
eventValues.SetType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Title, "Event Title");
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.Description, "Event Description");
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventBeginTime, GetDateTimeMS(2019, 3, 12, 16, 0));
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.ExtraEventEndTime, GetDateTimeMS(2019, 3, 12, 18, 0));
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventTimezone, "America/New_York");
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventEndTimezone, "America/New_York");
eventValues.PutExtra(CalendarContract.Events.InterfaceConsts.EventLocation, "Event Location");

StartActivity(eventValues);
```

Add event:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Any idea how I can get this to display the right time?

UPDATE

Nevermind this, the issue was in the GetDateTimeMS function that I got from Xamarin Docs. I had to change the timezone from default to the actual TZ:

```
long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
{
    //Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
    Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.GetTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, day);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hr);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, min);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Month, month);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Year, yr);

    return c.TimeInMillis;
}
```

Comment: Did you check the `DateTime` Kind before entering the value in the calender?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: You must be having a `DateTime` object right? check what kind is it!!

Comment: I don't, if you're talking about the GetDateTimeMS that is the time in milliseconds, it comes from the Xamarin docs. I will add the function to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the GetDateTimeMS function that I got from Xamarin Docs. I had to change the timezone from default to the actual TZ:

```
long GetDateTimeMS(int yr, int month, int day, int hr, int min)
{
    //Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.Default);
    Calendar c = Calendar.GetInstance(Java.Util.TimeZone.GetTimeZone("America/New_York"));

    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.DayOfMonth, day);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hr);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, min);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Month, month);
    c.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Year, yr);

    return c.TimeInMillis;
}
```